# Using vuetify variables in custom scss files in nuxt env

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

i am currently trying to acces vuetify variables inside my scss files. And i am using nuxt.

This is part of my nuxt.config.js

```
...
    buildModules: [
      '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
      '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
      '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
      ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { filename: '.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV }]
   ],
...
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true
  },
```

And then i have a component importing an scss file like so. And in this file i try to use: `var(--v-anchor-base)`

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import './NavigationDrawer.scss';
</style>
```

I guess it is because the scope scss file "dosen't know" of the vars from vuetify.
But how can i change it so i can use vuetify vars inside a scoped component?

Another point is that the documentation is missing for nuxt
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#nuxt-install

Comment: do you ever install node-sass and sass-loader ?

Comment: This should not be needed since its done by nuxt, i think.

Comment: I just tested this out in a non-Nuxt project and Vue had no problem getting the value of the Vuetify CSS vars from within a scoped SCSS section that imported a file. Could you post your Vuetify config file (in `src/plugins/vuetify.js` in a non-Nuxt project--not sure where it is in Nuxt)? Have you confirmed that `theme.options.customProperties` is `true`?

Comment: @morphatic that was it i only set customProperties to true but i did not know that it was inside the theme.options object. Thank you